Is there a way to reinit a postgresql docker compose stack without deleting it?
I'm learning PSQL and have SQL files copied or mounted to a docker container in a compose file. These are mounted in the PSQLs initdb. All is well and they get executed, however if I have a syntax error, the execution stops and the script won't be applied.
The only way I found to fix this is to, well, first fix the SQL, then docker compose down, then delete the stack along with the volumes. But is there a better way? One where I could just restart the PSQL service and it would register the initdb scripts again, without the need to tear down the whole compose stack and volumes?

You can always just manually run SQL files with psql. Or have I misunderstood the question?

I assume you mean run as in an interactive shell inside the container? It is a possible way of fixing this yes, but more-so is the question about how can I trigger the initdb scripts again, without having to delete and reinstantiate the entire compose stack again. Do you suggest editing the question to make it more clear?

... just re-init the db and run the top-level script then? I'm still not quite understanding I'm afraid.

I'm not understanding what you're not understanding - inception :). Maybe I am missing some key knowledge here, but what do you mean by re-init the db?
I am probably getting this wrong, but I want to avoid any interactive "shell-ing" into the psql container - at least for initing the actual db. Maybe I have to give a better description - my sql script fails due to some syntax error and my tables inside the schema do not get created, now because I am running this in docker compose the only way to fix it is I presume to fix the sql files I mounted in the yml file, tear down the stack 'n repeat

As in, to remount the newly fixed sql files and re-init the db that way. Or in other words to again trigger the docker-initdb entrypoint of psql images with the new sql files.

You say you don't want to recreate the container involved and you don't want to run the script manually. I don't know what other options might be available.

Exactly my question, anyway to just re-trigger the initdb scripts? Other than the methods mentioned? Otherwise I think I might have misjudged the purpose of initdb itself.
